# How to split an element with jQuery when a class is matched?

Tags: jquery

What I want is to be able to split an ul into two or more pieces, whenever the class "splithere" is matched. Then I need to wrap each part in a container. Like so:

```
<ul class="someclass">
    <li>One</li>
    <li>Two</li>
    <li>Three</li>
    <li class="splithere">Four</li>
    <li>Five</li>
    <li>Six</li>
    <li class="splithere">Seven</li>
    <li>Eight</li>
    <li>Nine</li>
</ul>
```

And what I want to end up with this:

```
<ul class="someclass">
    <li class="newclass">
        <ul>
            <li>One</li>
            <li>Two</li>
            <li>Three</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="newclass">
        <ul>
            <li class="splithere">Four</li>
            <li>Five</li>
            <li>Six</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="newclass">
        <ul>
            <li class="splithere">Seven</li>
            <li>Eight</li>
            <li>Nine</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>
```

I hope someone can help me...

Comment: It is a matter of using `jQuery.each()` and gathering subitems for `li.newclass` items. Just create new element and put any following elements as soon as you start or later find element having `splithere` class. Just basic task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
$(".someclass .splithere, .someclass li:first").each(function() {
    var li = $('<li class="newclass"></li>').insertBefore(this);
    var ul = $("<ul>").appendTo(li);
    $(this).nextUntil(".splithere")
        .add(this)
        .appendTo(ul);
});​
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/TTRhc/

---

Simplified it a little more:

```
$(".someclass .splithere, .someclass li:first").each(function() {
    var li = $('<li class="newclass"><ul></ul></li>').insertBefore(this);
    $(this).nextUntil(".splithere").add(this).appendTo(li.find("ul"));
});​
```

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/bC5J9/

Comment: This is cleaner than my example.  It would've been appropriate to add two more variables into my example to clean it up a bit.

Comment: I modified it slightly to make sure it includes the first set of li tags into their own block as the question shows.  That's a little inconsistent since they aren't in a splitthere, but that's the output the OP shows.

Answer (score 0):

You want something like this:

```
 $('.splithere').each(function(index){
       var masterIndex=$('ul.someclass li').index(this),
       listObj=$('ul.someclass li:eq(' + masterIndex + ')).add($('ul.someclass li:eq(' + masterIndex +')').nextUntil($('.splithere').eq(index+1)),
       wrapper=$('<li class="newclass"><ul>' + listObj + </ul></li>');
       $('ul.someclass li:eq(' + masterIndex + ')').add($('ul.someclass li:eq(' + masterIndex + ')').nextUntil($('.splithere').eq(index+1)).replaceWith(wrapper);
 })
```

What this does is:
1. Gets a master index - i.e. the index of this list item within the list
2. creates an object (listObj)  that includes this splithere and the list items until the next split here, and wraps them with the ul and li per your desired result
3. Replaces the original list item and its siblings with the new dom structure

I haven't tested it, but this should work.